# Telerik Radwindow collapses when overflow is hidden for IE 9

Tags: html, telerik, overflow, radwindow

I have a simple page that pops up a telerik radwindow on button click.
But opens as collapsed in IE 9. Works fine with FF, Chrome, IE 8, IE Compatibility Mode.
Look at the below screenshots of how they open.

IE 9
[image: IE 9]

Firefox
[image]

Heres the page code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" />
    <telerik:RadButton ID="btnOpen" runat="server" Text="Open" OnClick="btnOpen_Click" />
    <br />
    <telerik:RadWindow ID="TestDialog" runat="server" Title="Select Order Services"
        VisibleStatusbar="false" AutoSize="true" AutoSizeBehaviors="Height" Width="400px"
        Modal="true" VisibleOnPageLoad="false" Behaviors="Close, Move" EnableShadow="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="overflow: hidden;">
                <table cellspacing="0" border="0"
                    style="table-layout: auto; ">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 100px;">Column 1</th>
                            <th style="width: 100px;">Column 2</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                a
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                a
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                b
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                b
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                c
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                c
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </telerik:RadWindow>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestDialog.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
        }
```

I want the `overflow:hidden` present in the style and still want the pop up opened fully in IE 9. How do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way.

```
<ContentTemplate>
            <div style="display: inline; overflow: hidden;">
...
```

This is a solution, but I dont really understand how this works! That was one lucky line of code I wrote!
If any one can explain me why it works, I will mark theirs as answer.